# Save not saving in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Can't figure out why this isn't saving..

I've shortened my code for brevity, leaving out `end` and other un-important things.

I have this getting hit in a controller:

```
create_barbie = Barbie.new(params.require(:barbie).permit(:merchant_id,
:auth_token,:marketplace))
huh = create_barbie.save! #this is returning ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved   
#(Failed to save the record)
```

Before it fails `create_barbie` looks like this:

```
id: nil, merchant_id: "A340I3XXXX", auth_token: "13245", marketplace:   
"abcded", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, shopify_domain: nil, shop_id:  
nil, three_speed: nil>
```

So my `params` are coming over fine, and getting populated, just some reason the record isn't saving??

And in my `Barbie` model I have the following:

```
class Barbie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  validates :merchant_id, presence: true
  validates :auth_token, presence: true
  before_save :assign_three_speed
  NON_US_MARKETPLACES = ["1234", "abcd"]
```

In a private method within the `Barbie` model I have this:

```
private
  def assign_three_speed
    if NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?(marketplace)
      self.three_speed = false
    else
      self.three_speed = true   
    end
  end
```

All the data is correct, and the fields are getting set, its just not saving.. No idea why??

Comment: check `create_barbie.errors` after `create_barbie.save`

Comment: I will now!! I didn't know how to get to them.. I was using `huh.inspect` and it was only giving me true/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, indeed, with your `before_save` hook. The thing with the hook is that it can *cancel* the save operation if it returns `false`. And in your case it does return `false`. If you don't intend to cancel save, return a truthy value always.

```
  def assign_three_speed
    if NON_US_MARKETPLACES.include?(marketplace)
      self.three_speed = false
    else
      self.three_speed = true   
    end

    true # don't cancel save
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

First a little tip: Use `save!` during development when you aren't sure why it does fail. This will raise an exception with the validation errors instead of just returning `false`.

For your problems use `permit`:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

`Barbie.new(params.require(:barbie).permit(:merchant_id, ...))`

Comment: that makes total sense, the only issue is that its still not working.. real confused now.. I've updated my code to show what I'm doing now